# Could not load wrapper properties from 'C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'

Tags: android

Could not load wrapper properties from 'C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.

Am getting this error when I created new project in Android studio.

Comment: Please share the complete error log to get help.

Answer (score 2):

It is a common problem in Android Development. You can easily fix that.

Open`C:\Users\\[Username]\\.AndroidStudio4.0\system\` and delete the "caches" folder. After that create new project in Android Studio and all will works great.

Comment: but I cant find system folder from arctic fox

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\Pushpa\.android\cache
```

By deleting this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\(you user)\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\caches
```

you have to delete the cache folder