# Could not load wrapper properties in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

please help me, when i create a new project in android studio there is an error
Could not load wrapper properties from Could not load wrapper properties from 'C:\Users\baren\AndroidStudioProjects\ToyaGarage\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQeVS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t7pz.png)

Comment: It seems like the distributionUrl is missing in gradle-wrapper.properties of your project.

Comment: @EAS I have similar error, please where is the distributionURL suppose to be, and I'd appreciate a screenshot..

Comment: @Edwin distribution URL placed at gradle-wrapper.properties. cross check and update it, if it's not there, then place it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @EAS Thanks, I've checked it, it's there I tried making a few changes, but it still the same thing..

Comment: @Febriyandi Have you been able to fix, if yes, tell me how, please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Searched for your problem and i found this,maybe this solution can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/64439711/15805169

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I have a blank space at the end of "distributionUrl" row
[image: distribution url]

Comment: Thank you so much, removing the space fixed it for me when none of the other fixes here did anything.

Comment: Thanks same mistake here

Answer (score 0):

Delete the wrapper properties file in your app that is having the problem and copy the wrapper property file from your working apps to the same place where you deleted that file.

this is like the basic path to get to that file

```
C:\Users\TT Virtual\AndroidStudioProjects\KotlinFirebaseAuth\gradle\wrapper
```

remember this here is my path to that file

Comment: This worked for me and close android studio and restart it in administrative mode