# could not load wrapper properties from 'C:\Users\008\AndroidStudioProjects\CookpadAndroidApp\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-arctic-fox

`Could not load wrapper properties from 'C:\Users\008\AndroidStudioProjects\CookpadAndroidApp\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`'. when I create a new project every time it is giving this error above even I have installed and reinstalled android studio from scratch what is your suggestions
I have tried following links as well [Could not load wrapper properties in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70223147/could-not-load-wrapper-properties-in-android-studio) and [Could not load wrapper properties from 'C:\Users\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64438713/could-not-load-wrapper-properties-from-c-users-androidstudioprojects-test-grad)
I am using arctic fox in windows any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: try to delete .gradle folder => C:\Users\{username}\.gradle

Answer (score -1):

I solve problem by reinstalling android studio